# Finding row with coordinates inside a defined polygon in MySQL

Tags: mysql, gis, polygon, point

I'm trying to figure out how to go about returning a set of records which have coordinates within a polygon.

I have looked at the MySQL spacial extensions but they don't currently support searching within a specified polygon, only within the minimal bounding rectangle of the polygon.

I was wondering if anyone has come across this problem before and knew of any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If yes, Can you pls share your answer?

Comment: I never did I'm afraid. I ended up using PostgreSQL instead which has proper support for geographical queries.

Comment: one solution I came up with is that find 4 lat lngs of the polygon i.e. top, right, left and bottom. This will help us minify the results. Result will be based on rectangle shape. after which I used PHP point in Polygon class which will take care if the point lies in polygon or outside. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't (and won't be) built-in support for that, because determining if a point is within a generic polygon is a [rather complex problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).

Perhaps you should get the "candidate" points that fit into the bounding rectangle, then find the ones in the actual polygon by running them through one of those PIP algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

with [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?23,201913,201913) I have solve my similar issue... hope it helps.